# Setup method for nosetest. (Test class)

Tags: python, testing, installation, nosetests

I am mocking out a database in some tests that I am doing. How would I create a setup method for the entire class, such that it runs each time an individual test within the class runs?

Example of what I am attempting to do.

```
from mocks import MockDB

class DBTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setup(self):
        self.mock_db = MockDB()

    def test_one(self):
        #deal with self.mock_db

    def test_two(self):
        #deal with self.mock_db, as if nothing from test_one has happened
```

I'm assuming a teardown method would also be possible, but I can't find documentation that will do something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Python unit test framework something like this is what you want:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_db = MockDB()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass  # clean up 

    def test_1(self):
        pass  # test stuff
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html)

Answer (score 3):

With Nose, subclassing of TestCase works the same way as standard `unittest` -- `setUp`/`tearDown` are the same.  From [the nose docs](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-classes)

> Test classes
>
> A test class is a class defined in a test module that matches
>   testMatch or is a subclass of unittest.TestCase. All test classes are
>   run the same way: Methods in the class that match testMatch are
>   discovered, and a test case is constructed to run each method with a
>   fresh instance of the test class. Like unittest.TestCase subclasses,
>   other test classes can define setUp and tearDown methods that will be
>   run before and after each test method. Test classes that do not
>   descend from unittest.TestCase may also include generator methods and
>   class-level fixtures. Class-level setup fixtures may be named
>   setup_class, setupClass, setUpClass, setupAll or setUpAll; teardown
>   fixtures may be named teardown_class, teardownClass, tearDownClass,
>   teardownAll or tearDownAll. Class-level setup and teardown fixtures
>   must be class methods.